# How to enable scrolling after certain height EXTJS panel

Tags: extjs

How can we enable auto scrolling after extending upto certain height.

Basically my panel should extend automatically upto height 200 but post that I want scroll bar.

I gave

autoHeight:true
height:200
autoScroll:true

I don't want fix height 200 because height could be less than that at that time it should auto adjust to 100 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can have both autoHeight and height on an element (and have them both work) I think an explicit height and autoScroll true should give the effect you want except it won't collapse down below the height value obviously